# When, exactly, were the DC-8’s airbrakes removed?

Tags: airbrakes, dc-8

The DC-8 was originally equipped with airbrakes on the lower rear fuselage, but these were quickly removed.  [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_DC-8#Production_and_testing) that they were removed before the DC-8 entered service:

> [...]  Douglas made a massive effort to close the gap with Boeing, using no fewer than ten aircraft for flight testing to achieve FAA certification for the first of the many DC-8 variants in August 1959.  Much needed to be done: **the original air brakes on the lower rear fuselage were found ineffective and were deleted as engine thrust reversers had become available**...

Emphasis added.

However, according to [the CAB report](https://rosap.ntl.bts.gov/view/dot/33657) on the crash of [United Airlines Flight 859](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Airlines_Flight_859), the first few DC-8-10s, at least, *did* have airbrakes when they entered service, and at least one was using them as late as July 1961:

> When this action failed to straighten the landing roll he knew the aircraft was going to leave the runway.  **He said he used the emergency airbrakes to slow the airplane as much as possible before leaving the runway.**  [...]
>
> [...]  The second officer said that after touchdown a series of events occurred which he could not place in sequence with any degree of certainty.  He saw ejector indicator lights blinking, heard a foot thumper, **saw the captain reach for the emergency airbrake handle,** and saw that the aircraft was heading about 30 degrees off the runway.  [...]  [page 4 of the report]

Emphasis added.

And it’s definitely not misusing the term “airbrakes” to refer to the aircraft’s wing spoilers, since it refers to those as “spoilers” elsewhere in the report.

When *were* the DC-8’s fuselage airbrakes removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DC-8 is equipped with emergency air brake system. This isn't the type of air brakes you might expect on an airplane, but rather on a truck. The captain could pull a handle on the instrument panel to release pressurized air into the hydraulic brake system in the event of hydraulic pressure loss, as explained in [this AAIB bulletin](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/5422efd7e5274a13170002c5/dft_avsafety_pdf_500308.pdf). The fuselage air brakes were removed from the first prototype, no DC-8 entered service with them. Although the wing spoilers are not used as speed brakes in flight, reverse thrust is allowed on the inboard engines during descent.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense (although, in that case, the AAR should've referred to them as "air brakes" [air-actuated brakes], not as "airbrakes" [aerodynamic brakes]).